How do I make a Wordpress container start at the top of the page
I'm new to Wordpress blocks. On the home page the container and the background assigned to it start at the very top and the menu is superimposed over it.

But on new pages I create, there is a big gap of white space above the container. I cannot figure out how to make the container and it's background start at the top.


maybe you can select a different page template. try to duplicate the homepage maybe.

Tried that. Same result

that can depend on your theme. which one do you use ?

As I can check from the screenshot it looks like you are using Divi theme, so please try to use the steps given in the below link, it should able to help you out.
https://www.peeayecreative.com/divi-theme-builder-header-transparent-background/
